# What does the second number in the ranking table mean?

Tags: league-of-legends

Please see the following screenshot: What does the second number mean in the ranking table?
[image: https://ibb.co/59XW7zx]

Answer (score 2):

The second number refers to how many places the person has gone up or down over a period. I'm not sure how long exactly, as the actual number rank placement is pretty much irrelevant for any rank other than Master/Grandmaster/Challenger.